# Pseudo element on div not working with background

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a div which I want to style using the ::before pseudo-element, I’m doing this:

css:

```
&Item.isActive {
    &::before {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="sidebarItem">
  <div class="label">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it should look like.

[image]

This is how it is looking so far.

[image]

The background is not being added, any ideas why this could be happening? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Add some padding or margin? if not share your actual full code

Answer (score 0):

This is how I make it work,

css:

```
&Item.isActive {
    &::before {
        background: $brandColorSecondary;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 10px;
        height: 60px;
    }
}
```

[image]